# SignalR Server broadcast stops working when using DefaultDependencyResolver

Tags: c#, signalr

When starting a selfhost SignalR server, I can broadcast messages if I don't use a `HubConfiguration`

for example, broadcasting a message works fine using the following

```
// SelfHost 
public class SelfHostStartUp
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

but stops working when using this

```
// SelfHost
public class SelfHostStartUp
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HubConfiguration 
            { EnableJSONP = false, 
              EnableDetailedErrors = true, 
              Resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver() 
            };

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR(config);
    }
}
```

Server Side Event (outside of SignalRHub):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SignalRHub>();
    hubContext.Clients.All.SendMessageTest("Hello");
}
```

Client Side:

```
hubConnection = new HubConnection(ipAddressAndPort);
hubConnection.StateChanged += HubConnection_StateChanged;
hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
hubConnection.TraceWriter = new EventLogTraceWriter(eventLog1);
hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("SignalRHub");

hubProxy.On<string>("SendMessageTest", message =>
     Debug.WriteLine($"{message}")
);
```

There are no errors raised and server appears to send the message but client is not receiving anything. I need to be able to set the HubConfiguration, so can anyone help me determine why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Found a working solution, the default resolver in GlobalHost also needs to be set/reset

either of the following is working okay now

```
public class SelfHostStartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var defaultDependencyResolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver();
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = defaultDependencyResolver;
            var config = new HubConfiguration { EnableJSONP = false, EnableDetailedErrors = true, Resolver = defaultDependencyResolver };
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR(config);
        }
    }
```

or

```
public class SelfHostStartUp
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver();
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```